# jQuery: Get bound events, unbind and bind again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery extension/plugin which binds keydown events to `$(document)`. When I load a inline popup to my page I need to unbind certain events and then bind them again when it's closed.

What I've done so far is to get the bounded events with `$._data($(document)[0], "events");` and then unbind them with [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/). This far everything works as expected but when I try to bind them up again it does not work - the events are still unbound.

What seems to be wrong with the following code?

```
// This code runs when popup is clicked
var keydownEventsNamespace = [];
var keydownEvents = []; 
var events = $._data($(document)[0], "events");
if(typeof events.keydown !== \'undefined\') {                 
    $.each(events.keydown, function() {
        if ("" != $(this)[0]["namespace"]) {
            keydownEventsNamespace.push($(this)[0]["namespace"]);
            keydownEvents.push($(this)[0]);
        }
    });

    $.each(keydownEventsNamespace, function(index, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $("table.sort_navigate").length; i++) {
            var table = "navigator" + i;
            var keydownEventName = "keydown." + table;

            if (table == value) {
                // Unbind event!
                $(document).off(keydownEventName);

                // Bind again (later to be put in another place)
                $(document).on(keydownEvents[index]);
            }
        }                            
    });
}
```

Comment: a fiddle or plunker would help

Comment: Instead of unbinding events (which relies on an internal implementation detail), maybe you can have your event handlers check if a popup is present and bail out when it's the case?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, that is probably a better idea. Although it would be nice to know why my code fails..

Comment: Well, `$(document).on(keydownEvents[index])` only passes an event name, not a handler. It looks like you're not saving the event handlers in the first place.